# save form data using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am trying to save below form. please check my form html

### html

```
<form ng-submit="save()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.age"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.homenumber"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.road"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.city"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.school"/>
    <button type="submit">Save </button>
</form>
```

i saved this using below function.

```
$scope.save = function (){
    console.log($scope.user)
}
```

my result like below

```
{ name:"dais",
  age:"24",
  "homenumber":"23",
  "road":"new road",
  "city":"colombo",
  school:"new school"
}
```

but i need to save this form as a below json

requested one

```
{name:"dais",
 age:"24",
 "address":{
     "homenumber":"23",
     "road":"new road",
     "city":"colombo"
 },
 school:"new school"
}
```

can u help me to change my save function to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an address object for that purpose:

```
$scope.user = {};
$scope.user.address = {};

$scope.save = function () {
    console.log($scope.user);
}
```

```
<form ng-submit="save()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.age"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.address.homenumber"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.address.road"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.address.city"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.school"/>
    <button type="submit">Save </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.homenumber"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="user.road"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="user.city"/>
```

Should be

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.address.homenumber"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="user.address.road"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="user.address.city"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a constructor function

```
function DataToSave(data){
  this.name = data.name;
  this.age = data.age;
  this.address ={homenumber : data.homenumber, road:data.road, city:data.city };
  this.school = data.school
}
```

and use it like

```
 $scope.save = function (){
  let dataToSave = new DataToSave($scope.user);
  console.log(dataToSave);
}
```